# how populate select box with database in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an edit page where the data of a product is passed, on this page I have a select box for the category change, in it I need to insert all the categories registered in my database but only shows the category related to the product of the page.

**Select Box of Edit view**

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
          @foreach($produtos->categoria as $categoria)
          <option data-tokens="{{$categoria->erp_name}}" value="{{$categoria->erp_categoryid}}">{{$categoria->erp_name}}</option>
          @endforeach
          </select>
```

**ProdutosController**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $produtos = Produtos::find($id);

        return view('functions.edit')->with('produtos', $produtos);
    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/product/update/{id}', 'ProdutosController@edit')->name("product::updateGet");
Route::post('/product/update/{id}', 'ProdutosController@update')->name("product::updatePost");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Grab all of the categories, assign it to another variable, and pass that in as well. Then use that for the select instead.

Comment: Fetch using `$categories = Categoria::all()` and pass `->with('categories ', $categories )` then use that in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are looping through the categories of that product, not all categories. Here is a solution:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $produtos = Produtos::find($id);
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('functions.edit', compact('produtos', 'categories'));
}
```

then in your view:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      @foreach($categories as $categoria)
          <option data-tokens="{{$categoria->erp_name}}" value="{{$categoria->erp_categoryid}}">{{$categoria->erp_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```